# Warning: SHA1 algorithm and SHA1withRSA algorithm specified will be disabled in a future update

Tags: java, android, algorithm, ionic-framework, keystore

> **Warning:** The signer's certificate is self-signed. The SHA1 algorithm specified for the -digestalg option is considered a security
> risk. This algorithm will be disabled in a future update. The
> SHA1withRSA algorithm specified for the -sigalg option is considered a
> security risk. This algorithm will be disabled in a future update.

I'm trying to make production build for android using my **my-release-key.keystore** file with this command

> jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore
> my-release-key.keystore app.aab aliasName

and it shows me the warning, so, how can I resolve this warning and which algorithm do I use instead of it ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the documentation to see what the suggested replacement is.  SHA256 perhaps.  SHA1 is obsolete so you definitely need to replace it.

Comment: @Muhammad Usman any updates?

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this warning using SHA2 algorithm

```
sudo jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256 -keystore my-release-key.keystore /Volumes/Development/my_project/git_repo/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk aliasName
```